# problemas para criar várias tabelas no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu sou iniciante no uso do `Oracle`, usava o `firebird` antes. Gostaria de saber, o por que eu não consigo criar várias tabelas de uma única vez na planinha sql do `SQLdeveloper`. Ele cria apenas a primeira tabela (País).

Eu tento executar as seguintes instruções, para criar todas as tabelas de uma vez. (nesse caso estou utilizando apenas 3 tabelas para não ficar muito extenso).

```
CREATE TABLE PAIS
(
  IdPais INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NomePais VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  SiglaPais VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  StatusPais CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE PAIS ADD
(
  CONSTRAINT PAIS PRIMARY KEY (IdPais)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID_PAIS
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE
CYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_ID_PAIS BEFORE INSERT ON PAIS FOR EACH ROW BEGIN <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>> BEGIN IF :NEW.IDPAIS IS NULL THEN SELECT SEQ_ID_PAIS.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.IDPAIS FROM DUAL; END IF; END COLUMN_SEQUENCES; END;


CREATE TABLE ESTADO
(
  IdEstado INTEGER NOT NULL,
  IdPais INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NomeEstado VARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL,
  SiglaEstado VARCHAR(2)  NOT NULL,
  StatusEstado CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE ESTADO ADD
(
  CONSTRAINT ESTADO PRIMARY KEY (IdEstado)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID_ESTADO
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE
CYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_ID_ESTADO BEFORE INSERT ON ESTADO FOR EACH ROW BEGIN <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>> BEGIN IF :NEW.IDESTADO IS NULL THEN SELECT SEQ_ID_ESTADO.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.IDESTADO FROM DUAL; END IF; END COLUMN_SEQUENCES; END;


CREATE TABLE CIDADE
(
  IdCidade INTEGER NOT NULL,
  IdEstado INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NomeCidade VARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL,  
  StatusCidade CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE CIDADE ADD
(
  CONSTRAINT CIDADE PRIMARY KEY (IdCidade)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID_CIDADE
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE
CYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_ID_CIDADE BEFORE INSERT ON CIDADE FOR EACH ROW BEGIN <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>> BEGIN IF :NEW.IDCIDADE IS NULL THEN SELECT SEQ_ID_CIDADE.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.IDCIDADE FROM DUAL; END IF; END COLUMN_SEQUENCES; END;
```

Comment: Você esta executando como script?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo sim, eu estou ! (na planilha SQL -  alt+f10)

Comment: tente colocar sob cada comando a barra `/ ` e testa

Comment: @adventistaam como assim, a barra ? Onde colocar e qual a finalidade ?

Comment: eu faço isso no meu e funciona rsrs, é tipo um delimitador de cada comando

Comment: @adventistaam, certo, mais onde eu coloco especificamente ?

Comment: tal como @adventistaam indicou, coloque uma barra no final de cada create. ex: create table teste(id number); / create table teste2(id number);

Comment: @RenatoAfonso Certo, mais ele só funciona criando a tabela. Ele só funcionou deixando  os CREATE TABLE. Se eu for usar da maneira que esta no meu script não roda ! Para as criação da SEQUENCE e TRIGGER junto as tabelas não deu certo. (tentei adicionar ao final de cada ponto e vírgula também para testar, e não adiantou)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não me recordo se o Oracle Database permite que mais de um objeto tenha o mesmo nome. No script que postou, a chave primária de cada tabela está com o mesmo nome da tabela.

Você pode definir a chave primária de várias formas:

```
--código #2
CREATE TABLE PAIS
(
  IdPais INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NomePais VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
  SiglaPais VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
  StatusPais CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  constraint pkPAIS primary key (IdPais)
);
/
```

ou ainda

```
-- código #3
CREATE TABLE PAIS
(
  IdPais INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NomePais VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
  SiglaPais VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
  StatusPais CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
);
/
ALTER TABLE PAIS
  ADD pkPAIS primary key (IdPais);
/
```

Se não for necessário nomear a restrição, também pode utilizar esta forma:

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE PAIS
(
  IdPais INTEGER NOT NULL primary key,
  NomePais VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
  SiglaPais VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
  StatusPais CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
);
/
```

Comment: ele aceita com o mesmo nome, o problema que eu estou enfretando, é que ele não cria todas as tabelas de uma única vez. Utilizando o Script que eu postei como exemplo. Se eu compilar uma tabela de cada vez, ai ele funciona. Quando eu tento executar as 3 tabelas juntas, ele me da o seguinte erro: Erro(3,1): PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo "CREATE"  (este erro aponta para a linha do  NomePais VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,).

Comment: @AlunoOracle: Depois que você cria uma tabela de cada vez, você executa os demais comandos, um de cada vez e também não ocorre erro? Se for isso, também me parece a falta da / delimitando cada bloco de execução. Entretanto, o número da linha de erro é que é estranho.  ||| O código #3 que postei como exemplo, ele executa sem erros?

Comment: usei o código #2, estava certo, o que ocorre é que eu não havia delimitados todas as partes com o /. Agora deu certo, muito obrigado e desculpe !

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, a maneira correta de criar uma FK via script seria:                                                                                          FOREIGN KEY (IdPais)
REFERENCES PAIS (IdPais) no caso da tabela ESTADO.

Comment: @AlunoOracle: Pode ser feito através de ALTER TABLE ou então direto na declaração da tabela. //  ... CONSTRAINT fkPais FOREIGN KEY (IdPais) REFERENCES PAIS (IdPais)

Comment: da maneira que citei acima esta incorreto ?  FOREIGN KEY (IdPais) REFERENCES PAIS (IdPais)